# Extending a Sitemap

Tags: xml, xsd, sitemap

I have a website that contains a sitemap.xml file. Currently, my sitemap.xml file looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.mysite.com/about/blog/post-1</loc>
    <lastmod>2013-08-13</lastmod>
    <changefreq>never</changefreq>
    <blog:title>This is the title of the blog post</blog:title>
    <blog:description>This is the description of the blog post</blog:description>
    <blog:author>Some person</blog:author>
    <blog:authorUrl>https://www.mysite.com/people/some-person</blog:authorUrl>    
  </url>
</urlset>
```

As my snippet above shows, I'm trying to extend my sitemap. I'm using the approach detailed at sitemaps.org in the [extending the sitemaps protocol](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#extending) section.

I've created an .xsd file called blog.xsd. That file is located at http://www.mysite.com/data/blog.xsd. That file looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:simpleType name="title">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="description">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="author">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="authorUrl">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
  </xs:simpleType>  
</xs:schema>
```

I am trying to figure out how to reference blog.xsd in my sitemap file. Currently, the Google webmaster tool flags my sitemap.xml with warnings. My warning says: "This tag was not recognized. Please fix it and resubmit.". The warning is in reference to the title, description, author, and authorUrl tags.  I suspect this is because my sitemap.xml file does not reference blog.xsd. However, I do not know how to do that. Can someone please provide an example? The documentation on sitemaps.org is not very clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My tip is to read up on XML and namespaces in general; it will help you understand topics like this better.

As you can see in the [sitemap documentation](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) you can extend a sitemap with your own elements in their own namespace. You are missing one crucial part in your xml: although you used the namespace prefix `blog:` on your elements, you never declared a namespace prefix `blog`.

In the sitemap documentation you see:

```
<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"
     xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
     xmlns:example="http://www.example.com/schemas/example_schema"> <!-- namespace extension -->
```

It is this last part, **`xmlns:example="http://www.example.com/schemas/example_schema"`** that is crucial.

You need to come up with a namespace uri for your blog prefix. It only has to look like a URL, it doesn't actually need to exist. Let's use `http://www.mysite.com/data/blog/1.0` - you can use anything else as well.

Then your sitemap becomes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
        xmlns:blog="http://www.mysite.com/data/blog/1.0">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.mysite.com/about/blog/post-1</loc>
    <lastmod>2013-08-13</lastmod>
    <changefreq>never</changefreq>
    <blog:title>This is the title of the blog post</blog:title>
    <blog:description>This is the description of the blog post</blog:description>
    <blog:author>Some person</blog:author>
    <blog:authorUrl>https://www.mysite.com/people/some-person</blog:authorUrl>    
  </url>
</urlset>
```

That should be enough, according to the sitemap documentation.

If you also want to be able to validate the sitemap XML using an XML Schema validator, you can change the `<urlset` to:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
        xmlns:blog="http://www.mysite.com/data/blog/1.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
                            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd
                            http://www.mysite.com/data/blog/1.0 
                            http://www.mysite.com/data/blog.xsd">
```