# How to add comment in XML sitemap

Tags: xml, sitemap

I want to add comment tag in my manually generated XML sitemap to grouping urls like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <!-- Book -->
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/Book</loc>
  </url>
  <!-- Notebook -->
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/Notebook</loc>
  </url>
  <!-- Pen -->
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/Pen</loc>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you show us what you have already tried?

Comment: What are you using to generate that site map?

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/-jREphK2ul4

Comment: Try extending the protocol and adding the comments inside tags. See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/21554290/3144159

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That should be fine, in the sitemap protocol there is an example with a comment like the ones you used: http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#extending

```
<!-- my comment -->
```