# Can I use block comments in sitemap

Tags: web-crawler, sitemap, google-crawlers

I am very new to SEO and how sitemap xml works and recently I was given task to remove a few URLs from our sitemap.xml file.
To be safe, instead of removing the urls from sitemap, I just used a blocked comment to comment the URLs. But during code review, I was told that commenting in sitemap won’t work and these passes will still get crawled, and I was told to remove the URLs altogether.
I did some research and found out that comments work fine in sitemap but I couldn’t find and source saying that block comments are parsed or are not parsed by Google web crawlers.

Example of my blocked commented sitemap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <!-- Book -->
  <url>
   <loc>http://example.com/Book</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
      <loc>http://example.com/Notebook</loc>
    </url>
    <!--
     <url>
      <loc>http://example.com/Pen</loc>
     </url> ––>
   </urlset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `<!-- XXXXX --->` comments in XML sitemaps.   That style of comments is valid in any XML document and sitemaps are no exception.

See [How to add comment in XML sitemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117875/how-to-add-comment-in-xml-sitemap)

Comment: Thanks. Could you also help me with if block comments are supported in sitemap. I am aware of line comments but not sure about block commented out URLs (like Pen URL in my example).

Comment: Yes, that is fine.  That is just another of the same comment.